# when i use git pull origin development:yinronghui i got rejected non-fast-forward

Tags: git, github

```
git pull origin development:yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/jackiewillen/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 150, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (138/138), done.
remote: Total 150 (delta 90), reused 16 (delta 4)
Receiving objects: 100% (150/150), 19.02 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (90/90), completed with 58 local objects.

From ssh://git.dianpingoa.com/ed-f2e/gandalf-plus
 ! [rejected]        development -> yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822 (non-fast-forward)
   c391a9d..007bb97  development -> origin/development
```

my branch have been committed and push to yinronghui branch,then i use `git pull origin development:yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822` i got the error,i dont know why?

Comment: Are you asking about what the error means or how to fix it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how to fix it,how can i pull success

Comment: `git pull origin development:yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822` tries to overwrite the local `yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822` branch with what's in the remote `development` branch. This is normally not what you want, because if `development` doesn't have all of the commits that are in your other branch, this will remove them. What did you actually want to do?

Comment: @JanKrüger  my branch(yinronghui...)is pull from the development branch many days ago,i work on my branch(yinronghui...)and do many commit.other people also push some things to the development,so i need to  pull from the development to get the new code.but when i use git pull origin development:yinronghui.. i got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion here. The command you used does *not* merge development into your branch. Recall that `git pull` combines `git fetch` and `git merge`. The argument `development:yinronghui-shopcollect-20170822` is what's called a *refspec*. It tells `git fetch` which branches to fetch and where to store them.

Normal fetching stores the remote branches locally in a special namespace, so that you can compare your local branches to them, merge them, etc. You can see the fetched branches using `git remote -r`. A branch `development` fetched from `origin` usually shows up as `origin/development`.

Your `git pull` tells `fetch` to not use that special namespace but instead try to overwrite your branch directly, without merging, which would make any unpushed commits on your branch disappear and cause all kinds of other confusion. Git realizes that you probably didn't want to do that, and gives you an error to be safe.

#### Solution

The standard way to do this is to do this as a local operation.

1. Make sure your local `development` is up-to-date (optional, you can merge only what you've got if you like).
2. Checkout your branch.
3. Merge development locally: `git merge development`